# Is it possible to get this object's name?

Tags: java, reflection

Is this at all possible?

```
public class Clazz
{
  public String myName()
  {
    return Magic.getVariableName(this);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Clazz foo = new Clazz();
    System.out.println(foo.myName());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Of course, replacing `Magic.getVariableName(this);` with code that would actually get the variable's own name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects don't have names. Variables have names, fields have names, methods have names, classes have names, packages have names. However local variable names are discarded by the Java compiler.

In this case you would be at best able to get the name of the variable that points to the object. However, here that would be the name of `this`, which is 'this', and you already know that, so it isn't much use.

Answer (score 3):

Local variables?  No, they're erased by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

what you try to do is not possible the way you write it.
To understand why, maybe it helps you to remember that any object can be referenced by multiple variables, or handed over as arguments with different names - that's why you can't have a direct connection.
Maybe you can achieve your goal with an annotation.
Regards,
Blue

Comment: It's not possible at all. Nothing to do with the way he writes it.